# Magento2 home page is loading css, js and image of other pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

When Home page is loading, it's also loading checkout page css, js and other page images. What could be the possible reasons?

for example : when we are loading home page, it loading css and js of payment gateway, images of other static page like privacy policy. Which eventually increases page loading time of home page.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by saying it's other page images? Do you mean they apperar on the frontend? Could you provide us some more info?

Comment: for example : when we are loading home page, it loading css and js of payment gateway, images of other static page like privacy policy. Which eventually increases page loading time of home page.

Comment: Its kinda hard to believe that privacy policy cms page images are loaded on the home page. I believe you have some non standart solutions that can cause this. 
As for css that is loaded on other pages - it may be that your css is hooked on default scope - meaning it will be loaded on all pages.